# Nginx - location block misconfigured?

Tags: nginx, centos

I have a location block inside of my sites-enabled example.conf that should be routing /testing to a 503 error html page but instead for some reason its hitting my app instead of nginx

```
[2020-06-30T20:36:13.821768 #6059] FATAL -- : [fc9cb972-f314-4a87-89d9-8334521767b3] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/testing"):
```

that is a log line from my actual rails app - why is it even getting this far vs nginx routing to where I thought I told it to???

my nginx .conf

```
server { listen 443 ssl;

        server_name status.* www.status.*;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server_example.com.key;

        # logging
        access_log /var/log/nginx/status.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/status.error.log;

# security
        include security.conf;

        # reverse proxy
        location / {
         if (-f /opt/staytus/staytus/maint.on) {
            return 503;
        }
        port_in_redirect off;
                proxy_pass http://example.com:8787/;
        }

error_page 503 @maintenance;
           location @maintenance {
                root /usr/share/nginx/html
                rewrite ^(.*)$ /Performing-Maintenace.html;
           }

location = /testing/ {
    return 500;
        }


}

server {
listen 80;
        server_name www.status.* status.* 11.22.123.456;
    root /opt/staytus/staytus/public;
    client_max_body_size 50M;


        # SSL
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
        port_in_redirect off;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
   
    location @puma {
      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://example.com:8787;
 }
}
```

Comment: `/testing` isn't equal to `/testing/`. HTTP error 500 won't get you an error page defined for error 503.

Comment: Either way with or without the trailing slash in the confg seems to make zero difference

Comment: You're missing semicolon in `root /usr/share/nginx/html`. Is it a typo or you have this on your server? Testing your config with `nginx -t` is always a good practice when you made changes to your nginx config.